# How to detect touches on UITableView, nothing seems to work so far?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, touch

How can I detect a touch on a `UITableView`? I tried the solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848221/touch-events-on-uitableview). I have my `tableView` and a `scrollView` in the same `UIViewController` with a constraint, so it is complicated to subclass the `tableView`.
The touches methods are not called:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var verticalSpacing: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    println("touch began")
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    println("touch ended")
}
override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

I added:

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
tableView.canCancelContentTouches = false //or true is the same
```

but it doesn't change anything. The `scrollView` is visible at the same time as the `tableView`, but they are not overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are methods that can be useful when working with UITableView that detect changes to the scrollview. These may be useful for you.

For example,

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    println("Ended decelerating")
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    println("Ended dragging")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use willBeginDragging and DidEndDragging, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 10):

No subclassing required!

Just add a gesture recognizer and be sure to include a call to `cancelsTouchesInView`

Here's the Swift version:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:"))
}

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        // Do your thang here!
    }
    sender.cancelsTouchesInView = false
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that `touchesBegan` etc. are also methods from `UIView` so you need to either subclass the `UITableView` or use a TapGestureRecognizer to make it work like you need it.

It shouldn't be too complicated to subclass the `UITableView` because you can just set your UITableView class as the class of your tableView in your Storyboard, like you do with UIViewControllers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adjusting `delaysContentTouches`?  It could be that if you pressed long enough your touches would register with the default delay.

Have to ask, is there a reason why you cannot just use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Thanks, I will stay with the willBeginDragging and DidEndDragging which seem to work. I had to check the scroll and cancel it when the user stopped dragging. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I needed to detect touch ***not tap*** on table so I wound up with this:

```
fileprivate class TouchSensitiveTableView: UITableView {

    fileprivate var onTouchStart: (() -> ())? = nil
    fileprivate var onTouchEnd: (() -> ())? = nil

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.onTouchStart?()
    }

    public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.onTouchEnd?()
    }
}
```

Then use like this

```
private let tableView = TouchSensitiveTableView()

viewDidLoad() {
    ....
    self.tableView.onTouchStart = {[weak self] in .... }
    self.tableView.onTouchEnd = {[weak self] in .... }
```

Has a minor interaction with the scrolling of the table, but nothng major.

Comment: Well the taps in the UITableView stops with this solution...