# Handle Touch in UiCollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have this big `UICollectionView` occupying major part of screen and there is a `UIButton` that shows a menu. I want to hide the menu when the user taps on any side of the screen which becomes unfortunately any part of `UICollectionView` for me. Tried on other view the below code, it works well...but not for `UICollectionView`. The function does not gets called.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {            
   hidemenu()
   self.view.endEditing(true)            
}
```

What is the problem? Thanks for your time.

**OR**
How to trigger `touchesBegan` in the `UIViewController` where `UICollectionView` resides

**[Here is the project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6dTvD1JbkgBLTBHQklEWFZESzA&authuser=0)**

Comment: You can try by disabling userinteraction of collection view when menu opens , this way `touchesBegan` should be called. You can enable it again when menu is closed.

Comment: i cannot do that...menu and collection view are in different class..so quiet complex i  think

Comment: Ok , than this thread might help you. Here its discussed for tableview , you can try same for collectionview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848221/touch-events-on-uitableview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While tapping on scrolling controllers (like UIScrollView, UITableView, UICollection etc) does not call `touchesBegan` method. because they have their own `selector` method. To handle such situation, you need to create `UITapGesture` on `UICollectionView`. While tapping on `UICollectionView`, its selector method called and do what ever you want.

Here are the link that guide you. how to create double Tap Gesture on `UICollectionView`. with help of this you can created single Tap gesture as well.

[Collection View + Double Tap Gesture](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/09/28/collection-view-default-gestures.html)

**Edit :**
 Do the following changes, it work fine.

**Step 1** : Declare `handleTap` in `SwipeMenuViewController`.

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        println("called swipe")

    }
```

**Step 2** : Create global variable of `SwipeMenuViewController` controller. that is out side of `viewDidLoad()`

```
var vc2 = SwipeMenuViewController()
```

[image]

**Step 3** : Declare `TapGesture` in `viewDidLoad()`

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: vc2, action : "handleTap:")
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**Output** :

called swipe

Hope this help you.

Comment: ok i am trying this..but i want the target to another viewcontroller because the method that hides the menu is in other class...it doesnot work...can i assign target to another class?

Comment: var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: SwipeMenuViewController(), action : "show")

        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)   but the action doesnot get call..it throws and exception unrecognized selector sent to an instance

Comment: but doesnot...i checked the method name..its fine...: (

Comment: right now i am chating with help of phone. i will check out and inform you. still you can redirect tap gesture event from current class to another class with help of delegate.

Comment: @copeME, i have checked out scenario and it seems working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77298/discussion-between-copeme-and-none).

Comment: i have uploaded project please have alook

Comment: @copeME, i am unable to download it. can you please upload it on dropbox.

Comment: @copeME, check my edited answer. here need to create global variable instead of local variable.

Comment: hey thanks man!!! i dont have mac at home....will implement it tomorrow at office :)...anyway i will accept your answer

Comment: Actually you declared local variable inside viewdidload so once you tapped on collection view that object is deallocated so crash happened

Comment: did you try calling the hideMenu() method..instead if printing called swipe.....i have got some problem there

Answer (score 6):

You can add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UICollectionView and create an action to dismiss the view if the user touch outside your collection or anywhere.

**Step 1** Create a tap gesture for dismiss the view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     ...

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOutsideCollectionView(recognizer:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

**Step 2** With the tap location implement your desired action

```
@objc func didTapOutsideCollectionView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
    //The point is outside of collection cell
    if collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: tapLocation) == nil {
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can directly use this method , whenever user taps on any part of collection view , your menu will be automatically hidden:-*

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    hidemenu()
        self.view.endEditing(true)    
}
```

*To detect tap on  spaces between the cell, here is the code*

```
self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.collectionView.frame];
self.collectionView.backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
self.collectionView.backgroundView.gestureRecognizers = @[tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: might not work ..if i have large collection view and few cells on it ??

Comment: I don't think you are getting the point mate..  only tapping it works.

Comment: sorry..i was saying i must tapp a cell for that..i have some spaces between the cell..so what when the user taps on the space..so it doesnot work for me

Comment: ok..i am trying that...but setting target to another class doesnot call the action

Comment: what do you mean by "setting target to another class"?

Comment: var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: SwipeMenuViewController(), action : "handleTap:")

Comment: Can you just check by adding tap gesture to Collectionview not its background view, whether handleTap is getting fired or not?

Comment: i have uploaded project please have a look